# XLForm - How do I left align a cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xlform

I'm using the awesome library XLForm, but have run into a problem styling a XLFormRowDescriptorTypeSelectorActionSheet type row.

I would like the label to be left aligned, instead of right aligned as it is now.

I'm able to do this on other types of rows, but it does not work on the SelectionActionSheet type row

```
row.cellConfig["textLabel.textAlignment"] = NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo in your question or in your code?

```
row.cellConfig["textLabel.textAlignment"] = NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue
```

You've typed `.Center.` rather than `.Left`